# Cleanup process after program finishes execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that runs on an old machine having 4GB of memory.  When the program finishes execution, I noticed via [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) that the memory is still occupied. My question is: if I use:

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

Does it guarantee that the process is completely cleaned up from the memory after execution?

Comment: "When the program finishes execution" actually implie that the process has terminated, and by that time all the memory IS returned to the system. If you can still see the process in htop (or ps etc) then it means the program has __not__ "finished execution".

Comment: could it be you're using `threading`/`multiprocessing` and one of the processes/threads is not terminated properly? i think its a very common reason for python processes to stay open for more than they should

Answer (score 1):

Short version: no.

Long version: I don't think calling sys.exit(0) ensures that, memory management is handled at a different level from the OS.

When a script finishes python has no longer control over it (obviously).

If your script at some point calls some other external script or a weird function that you think might tamper with your memory that's another story.